# Enable and forward sound from an Amazon Linux 2 EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio, amazon-ec2, alsa, pulseaudio

I would like to forward sound from an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 to my local MAC so I can listen to any audio played.

I have been looking into if I can do something potentially with ALSA and/or PulseAudio to create the sound and use SSH to send the audio output but am a bit out of my depth trying to understand the technology.

I don’t believe the EC2 supports ALSA from the get go as I ran a troubleshooting script from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo and got the following info:

```
/proc/asound/modules: No such file or directory
/proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory
/tmp/alsa-info.pqBt6ov9wv/alsamodules.tmp: No such file or directory
/proc/asound/modules: No such file or directory
/dev/snd/*: No such file or directory
alsactl: save_state:1595: No soundcards found...
/tmp/alsa-info.pqBt6ov9wv/alsactl.tmp: No such file or directory
```

PulseAudio however is installed and gives the following information:
[image: PulseAudio output]

Does anyone know if this is possible to send the audio back to my MAC and how to implement?

Comment: if you just need to copy files and you have ssh keys setup which allow you to remote login to the EC2 instance then just `scp` a file from remote box to your local box ... google `scp` for details

Comment: To clarify sorry - I don't want to copy any audio files. I just want to play the audio from an EC2 through the speakers on my MAC as it happens. For example, you could watch a video on the EC2 and hear the video's sound playing.

Comment: You are presumably connecting via SSH, which does not provide an audio back-channel. You would need a way to send audio between two separate computers. Alternatively, you could launch an [Amazon WorkSpace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces.html), which is different to Amazon EC2. I know that it sends sound for Windows instances, and I _suspect_ that it works for Linux too.

Comment: For various reasons out of my control I have to use an EC2 which does have a GUI attached so I can access using VNC tools too. I was hoping after getting sound enabled I could do something similar to [here](https://joshdata.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/pulseaudio-sound-forwarding-across-a-network/). The audio there is forwarded over ssh but again I don't know how feasible this is.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using PulseAudio and RDP. Fair warning, when playing Youtube the audio is very stuttery and I was unable to fix it - I ended up just giving up and using a Windows Server 2022 instance instead. I did this with Windows Remote Desktop Connection but for Mac I assume you can use a RDP client like [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id1295203466?mt=12)

1. [Launch EC2 instance with MATE GUI desktop support, check Allow RDP in security groups.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-mate.html).
2. Connect with RDP to the EC2 instance, using the instance's public IPv4 address.
3. Run the following to install pulseaudio and pulseaudio-module-xrdp:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils pulseaudio-libs-devel git gcc m4 intltool libtool libtool-ltdl-devel libcap-devel libsndfile-devel
cd ~
curl https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/releases/pulseaudio-10.0.tar.gz --output pulseaudio10.tar.gz
tar -xzf pulseaudio10.tar.gz
pulseaudio-10.0/configure
git clone https://github.com/neutrinolabs/pulseaudio-module-xrdp.git
cd pulseaudio-module-xrdp
./bootstrap && ./configure PULSE_DIR=~/pulseaudio-10.0/configure
make
sudo make install
usermod -a -G audio ec2-user
sudo reboot
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

Audio does play but it is again stuttery on Youtube.

I tried various tips such as [this StackOverflow answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560545/problem-with-audio-stuttering-choppy-in-every-single-distribution-ive-used) but gave up as I couldn't figure out how to install pipewire on Amazon Linux 2. My next thought would be to try to use Amazon Debian with Pipewire and pipewire-module-xrdp, but I have no idea if it would work.